# How to have multiple facets or repeats with concatenated layers?

Tags: javascript, plot, vega-lite, vega

I am trying to build a bunch of box plots with **vega-lite** that are concatenated into one plot.  The number of box plots will be dependent on how many variables the user selects.

As an example dataset I have the following variables: tissue, sex, and age.

- Tissue has 5 values: fat, heart, hippocampus, kidney, lung
- Sex has 2 values: Male, Female
- Age has 2 values: 8, 18

It's straight forward to create the plots with 1 or 2 variables selected.

Here is a plot by tissue by sex.

[image: Tissue by sex]

Here is my simplified spec to generate the first image:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "url": "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mattjvincent/5d65bdb43afcfa145a09d0d59f2dd769/raw/b1cfadace31170717ab8f0aad742ffbd248ee494/simpledata.json",
    "format": {"type": "json"}
  },
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "random()", "as": "jitter"},
    {
      "calculate": "if(datum.sex === 'Female', random() - 1, random() + 1)",
      "as": "sex_1"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "if(datum.age == 8, random() - 1, random() + 1)",
      "as": "age_1"
    }
  ],
  "facet": {
    "column": {
      "field": "tissue",
      "title": null,
      "header": {"labelExpr": "upper(datum.label)", "labelFontWeight": "bold"}
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "width": 100,
    "layer": [
      {
        "mark": {"type": "boxplot", "color": "lightgrey", "ticks": true},
        "encoding": {
          "x": {"field": "sex", "type": "ordinal", "title": null},
          "y": {
            "field": "intensity",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "title": "Abundance",
            "scale": {"domain": [-5, 5]}
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "mark": "point",
        "encoding": {
          "x": {
            "field": "sex_1",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "axis": {"title": null, "labels": false, "ticks": false},
            "scale": {"domain": [-1.5, 2.5]}
          },
          "y": {
            "field": "intensity",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "axis": {"title": ""}
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "resolve": {"scale": {"x": "independent"}}
}
```

It's the 3rd variable (and eventually more variables) that has me stumped on how to code it.  I could create the spec with Javascript and keep concatenating layers, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution via multiple facets or repeats?

What I would like to generate (the formatting with colors, boxes doesn't matter):

[image: Tissue by sex than age]

Oh... and if anyone knows of a better way to do jittering with these plots, please share.